# In linear system give values of t so that system has no solution and a solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

$$2x − y = 5\ , \ 4x − 2y = t$$

(a) Determine a value of $t$ so that the system has a
solution.

(b) Determine a value of $t$ so that the system has no
solution.

What is the standard way to solve such questions?

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

(a) Assign a value to $x$, compute $y$ from $2x-y=5$ and calculate $t=4x -2y$.

(b) Note that if you multiply the first equation by $2$, we obtain $4x − 2y = 10$.